# Multiple IF ELSE statements not working on blur

Tags: javascript, html

I am having issues using multiple "if else" statements. One statement on its own works fine, but adding more statements makes things break. As each if else statement is exactly the same as the previous one I cannot establish what is causing the issue!
My task is to update the variable when an input box is amended, or if no amendment to use the original result from a mySQL query
I am using PHP, HTML & Javascript

```
$('body').on('blur keyup paste input', '[contenteditable]', function() {
document.getElementById("cancelchanges").style.display='none';
document.getElementById("savechanges").style.display='block';
 
 $d = document.getElementById("d").value;
 if ($d == "") {
 document.getElementById("nD").value = <? echo $dlr; ?>; 
 } else {
 document.getElementById("nD").value = $d;   
 }
 
 $c = document.getElementById("contact").value;
 if ($c == "") {
 document.getElementById("nC").value = <? echo $con; ?>; 
 } else {
 document.getElementById("nC").value = $c;   
 }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn’t there be quotes around each PHP tag?

Comment: document.getElementById("nC").value = $sc;  <-- should that be $c ?

Comment: Sorry that’s a typo on my behalf!!